# Plotting Cumulative Recalll Curve Python

Tags: python, data-science, text-classification, precision-recall

I’m trying to plot a cumulative recall that looks *like the following picture* any idea?
[image: Picture]

I want to be able plot the AUR as mention in this paper [Prioritising references for systematic reviews with RobotAnalyst: A user study](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/jrsm.1311)

So my problem is a classification problem but I have imbalanced dataset where the included references are limited. Example would be if I have 1,000 references only 90 should be consider relevant references.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Here is how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0):

I think AUR is similar to general Area Under Curve(AUC) / ROC curves. Check the link.

[Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC)](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html)

Comment: Still can’t figure it out. Not sure how to only plot the Recall against all data points.